# My http response code from NightmareJS is undefined

Tags: javascript, nightmare

Hi & welcome to 2017 :)

I am trying out NightmareJS in place of PhantomJS and so far so good (PhantomJS is performing very slowly for me hence the change)

My issue is when I try and return the http response header, the value is undefined.

I have looked through the docs and many examples and they all point show very similar code to mine.

I am checking the site/s I am opening by setting show to true so I know they actually open

Any help appreciated, cheers.

My current code is below:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');

var nightmare = Nightmare({
    show: false,
    switches: {
        'ignore-certificate-errors': true
    },
    webPreferences:{
        images: true
    },
    //waitTimeout: 1000,
    loadTimeout: 30000 //** If we cant reach the page after nnnn millseconds, timeout
});

//** Start nightmare
var ms = Date.now(); //** Set a timer
nightmare
.cookies.clearAll()
.goto(url)
.screenshot('abc123.png')
.end()
.then(function(httpResponse){
    console.log(httpResponse.code); //** <<<< Here SHOULD be the http response code
    console.log(Date.now() - ms);
    callback(siteObject); //
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
});
```

Comment: I have not worked out all the details yet, but if you remove .screenshot('abc123.png') it returns proper status response

Comment: Cheers Daniel that works.

There is the small problem of the screenshot not rendering :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens because of the line

```
.screenshot('abc123.png')
```

If you remove it, then `httpResponse.code` will return a status code.

<s>I believe this might be a bug - I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/940) with the developers, and I will get back to you with the response.</s>

**Update**

I just received a reply from **[rosshinkley](https://github.com/rosshinkley)** who is the largest contributor to nightmarejs:

> `httpResponse` is not defined because the parameters passed to `.then()` will be from the last action executed in the chain (with the exception of `.end()`) - in your case, `.screenshot()` (which doesn't return anything). If you need the HTTP response, you can break up your chain with another `.then()` to perform logic.

The original question can then be fixed with (again credit to **[rosshinkley](https://github.com/rosshinkley)**):

```
nightmare.goto(url)
.then(function(httpResponse) {
  if(httpResponse.code == 200) {
    return nightmare.screenshot('abc123.png');
  } 
  else {
    //error condition?
    throw new Error('http response was not ok');
  }
})
.then(function(){ return nightmare.end(); })
```

Comment: Excellent thanks.

Versions:

"nightmare": "^2.9.0"

node version: 6.9.1

Comment: I have added the reply @TheTechy

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I was just looking at that.

I have now tried that and the code is works. 

I am adjusting my head to remember nightmare is thenable so just need to remember to return any data required to subsequent then's

Thanks again to you & Ross